# Can scalatags be used together with binding.scala?

Tags: scala, scalatags, binding.scala

Binding.scala's examples contain Scala XML tags as a language to code DOM fragments. Can scalatags be used instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Binding.scala internally generates very sophisticated ScalaTags code. On the other hand, manually written naive ScalaTags code recreates entire DOM whenever the data changes.

Milad Khajavi created an example demonstrating the problem of the manually written ScalaTags code: https://gitter.im/ThoughtWorksInc/Binding.scala?at=581b6367eed0c3125f30d57b

ScalaTags is very convenient for simple application. However, since they are plain function calls that do not have any ability to partially update, ScalaTags is not a good choice for a complex interactive application if you need fine-grained update on DOM.

Comment: this answer is from 2017. is the answer still valid?

Comment: otherwise, there is scalatags-rx: https://github.com/rtimush/scalatags-rx