# Reactive components in binding.scala + scalatags

Tags: scala.js, binding.scala, scalatags

I want to do similar to [scalajs-bootstrap](https://github.com/Karasiq/scalajs-bootstrap) for my own css. But as per my knowledge it doesn't perform partial dom update like `Binding.scala` does. I know we can use `Binding.scala` and `scalatags` together base on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42893721/can-scalatags-be-used-together-with-binding-scala) but partial dom will not happen. Is there any solution?